# Makefile with sub-directories

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile for a C++ project, divided into directories:

- `makefile`
- `src` – (all the `.cpp` files)
- `include` (all the `.h` files)
- `obj` (all the `.o` files)
- `bin` (create the executable there)

I've read a lot about the subject but either it is too simple and they list the files manually or it is too complicated and I am lost.

I tried to write the makefile in many different ways and this is the last one:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS =  -std=c++11 -c -g -Wall

TARGET = bin/evolveIt

LINKER   = g++ -o
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm

# change these to set the proper directories where each files shoould be
SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
HDIR = include
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(HDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f


$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
```

But now I have this error:

```
src/PopulationManager.cpp:4:31: fatal error: PopulationManager.h: No such file or directory
 #include "PopulationManager.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'obj/PopulationManager.o' failed
make: *** [obj/PopulationManager.o] Error 1
```

I know that I have to use `-I` when the headers are in a different directory, but it is already in the `CFLAGS` and `LFLAGS` and it doesn't change anything if I put it directly in `INCLUDES` like this:

```
INCLUDES := -I $(wildcard $(HDIR)/*.h)
```

There is no error in the program itself, it compiled fine before I put into different directories. The point of this makefile was to avoid writing relative paths in my source files like

```
include "include/PopulationManager.h"
```

Any idea of what's wrong with this makefile?

Comment: I don't see `-I` in the `CFLAGS`. Also it should not be in the `LFLAGS`. Also your `TARGET` is `bin/evolveIt` and then you prefix it with `$(BINDIR)` giving `bin/bin/evolveIt`...

Comment: I thing @Galik is right, when I use `CFLAGS =  -std=c++11 -c -g -Wall -I$(HDIR)`, everything works properly on my computer

Comment: Have you checked the commands that make issues? When you having problem with make it's not wise to preceed the commands with `@`, when trouble shooting you actually want to see what make is doing. I guess that if you did omit the `@` you would see that make actually doesn't add the `-Iinclude` flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -c -g -Wall -I$(HDIR) and specifying target as evolveIt instead of bin/evolveIt ! I can't believe I spent so much time on this !